# Repeated (x 24) achievement notification

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

Today I got a notification for a single achievement ("Nice answer" badge) repeated, about 24 times - the screenshot shows the first ones. Never happened to me before.

[image]

Comment: Besides, the notification shows the [matheducators.se] (meta) logo instead of the [math.se] logo.

Comment: @DanielFischer If that is indeed wrong (it seems it is, I hadn't notice), then that problem appears in several places, eg in the "Hot Network Questions" sidebar...

Comment: Doesn't do that for me. You may be experiencing the resurrection of [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277518/all-stack-exchange-site-logos-are-showing-up-as-the-3d-printing-one).

Comment: This seems to be noticed on Meta.SE under [Badge notification repeats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283748/badge-notification-repeats).

Comment: It seems to be an [acknowledged global issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283748/badge-notification-repeats). It's being fixed.

Comment: I'd wish to close this question as duplicated of the link above, but I cannot do that because it's from another site...

Comment: @leonbloy: The wrong logo (I believe you are not even active on Math Educators?) seems to make this a somewhat novel instance.

Comment: @hardmath : the wrong logo (both in the notification area and in the sidebar) apparently has just been fixed.

Comment: The logo problem seems to propagate. My Meta.Math.SE links have MathOverflow logo and MathEducators.SE links seem to carry Mathematica.SE logo.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm also experiencing the logo-bog: My MSE logo is Math Educators, my metaMSE is MathOverflow, and my Mathematics Educators is the Mathematica SE.